# how to interpret messages with package dependencies problems using apt

Tags: debian, apt

I'm having some problems to install some packages in a Debian box. The problem is more related with the error message interpretation. I'm trying to install the libssl-dev. So I fired a shell and I typed:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

For my surprise i've got the following error:

```
libssl-dev: Depends: libssl0.9.8 (= 0.9.8o-4squeeze1) but 0.9.8o-6 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

So what exactly it means? It depends the libssl0.9.8 ( the squeeze1 version) but the 0.9.8o-6 will be installed? Is this minor number (the "o-6") a blocking for apt-get? Can I force it (I did try with the -f, but it didn't work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `libssl-dev` that APT would install requires version `0.9.8o-4squeeze1` of `libssl0.9.8`. The equal sign means “exactly this version”. Version `0.9.8o-6` is different, so it's a no go.

Run `apt-cache policy libssl-dev libssl0.9.8` to see what versions of these packages you have installed and what versions are available for installation. Post the output if you still need help.

If you meant to have a squeeze (stable) Debian, you shouldn't have `-6` anywhere, so you have a spurious package source. If you meant to have a wheezy (testing) or sid (unstable) Debian, you either have incomplete sources, or need to refresh the list of available packages with `apt-get update` first.

Comment: didn't solve my problem but answered my question